# Связь классов python kivy

Tags: python, kivy

У меня есть класс Container, который создает кнопку. Класс `MyApp` возвращает этот класс. Как мне сделать так, чтобы из класса `Pop` можно было поменять текст кнопки класса `Container`? Конструкция `self.button.text`  не работает

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
class Container(BoxLayout):
    pass

class Pop(BoxLayout):
    pass

class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):

        return Container()

TestApp().run()
```

Вот kv файл

```
<Container>:
    button:button
    BoxLayout:
        Button:
            id:button
            text:"s"
```

Comment: в кв ведь написано что контейнер.батон.текст его и менять.как менять ? при нажатии или по таймеру ? мало данных.

Comment: @SKIP, по нажатию